# How To Play Embedded Multiple Videos From Different Websites Back To Back When One Video Ends

Tags: javascript

I have an embedded playlist of video links from different websites like Dailymotion, YouTube, Vimeo, etc., that I would like to play back to back on a personal website that I am working on. I found a script on the internet that plays embedded videos from multiple websites, but it only plays one video randomly. I would like the script to play each video back to back once one video is finished playing, but since I have no skills whatsoever in javascript, I don't know how to adapt this script to meet my needs. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I would greatly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks! Here is the script:

```
        <div id="random_player"></div>

        <script>

        var videos = ["https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7raxfh?queue-enable=false","https://ok.ru/videoembed/3188453542586","https://www.youtube.com/embed/X3wV5ydVewY" ];
        window.onload = function () {
            var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
            var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            var randomVideoUrl = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
            player.setAttribute('width', '640');
            player.setAttribute('height', '390');
            player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);

            playerDiv.appendChild(player);
        };

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the step by step code below-

**Step 1**
Copy paste the below code in html file **by replacing url to your desired one**!-

```
<iframe src="url" id="videoPlayer" height="200"">
```

**Step 2**
Javascript file should look like this-

```
let videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0] = 'https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7raxfh?queue-enable=false","https://ok.ru/videoembed/3188453542586';
videoSource[1] = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/X3wV5ydVewY4';
let i = 0; // global
const videoCount = videoSource.length;
const element = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
 
function videoPlay(videoNum) {
    element.setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
    element.autoplay = true;
    element.load();
    element.play();
}
document.getElementById('videoPlayer').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
 
videoPlay(0); // play the video
 
function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == videoCount) {
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(i);
    } else {
        videoPlay(i);
    }
}
```

**Step 3**
Save the file and call the javascript file on html file. Open the html file in browser and  it will run according to your asked question!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I thought the <video> tag was only used for videos from a file source and not from a website source. I apologize if I did not clarify that. I updated my post to reflect that. I don't have any videos saved in a file, rather, I am using embedded links from various websites. I did, however, try your code, and it plays one video when I changed the <video> tag to an <iframe>, but it does not play the next video when the first video stops.

Comment: An iframe cannot know when the video has stopped. A video tag has an event `ended` you can see implemented above. You can see in the example how the videos URLs must look like - you can likely find that in the iframe code as well.

Comment: @PeterKrebs: I did not know that about iframes. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Uttam: I am so sorry. I must be doing something wrong. I copied the script and used the <video> tag, but all that shows up on my page is a dark gray video player with a blank screen. It just won't play a video. I tried putting the javascript into the html page and also tried calling it from an external js file, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @PeterKrebs sure buddy, I had done some modifications in the code, hope now it will work good now!

Comment: @Uttam I tried the new code with the iframe, but it only plays the url within the src attribute and does not cycle through the array to play the next video when it is finished playing. “Peter Krebs” mentioned above that an iframe doesn't know when a video has stopped, so maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks buddy, for sharing your issue! I will let you know if I will find any solution on this. @Noobie-000

Comment: @Uttam Oh, sure. Thank you very much for all the help you have already given me. I know more now than what I did a few days ago.